# centos + apache + uWSGI any option?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, uwsgi

I am trying to setup 'apache + uWSGI' on centos. But I am getting the following error:

> Invalid command 'uWSGISocket', perhaps misspelled..

For that I found a solution that I need a package called:

> libapache2-mod-uwsgi

But on centos that package is not available. Now I am confused whether 'apache + uWSGI' can be configured on centos?
following is my virtualhost config:

> LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so WSGISocketPrefix
>   /var/run/wsgi
>
> ```
> ServerName www.example.com
> ServerAlias example.com
> DocumentRoot /usr/src/example/templates
>
> <Location />
>     SetHandler uwsgi-handler
>     uWSGISocket 127.0.0.1:3031
> </Location>
>
> <Directory /usr/src/example/templates>
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Afaik stable CentOS is too old to have some form of uWSGI package. Btw installation is extremely easy. `pip install uwsgi` will be more than enough. Or eventually you can download the stable tarball and run `make`. Building `mod_uwsgi` (or `mod_proxy_uwsgi`) could be a little bit more annoying (be sure to install the `apache` development headers).

run it from the 'apache2' directory in uWSGI sources:

```
apxs2 -i -c mod_uwsgi.c
```

More info [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Apache.html)